# Label of checkbox diaplys but checkbox is not displaying

Tags: extjs, checkbox

I have following code-

```
{ fieldLabel: 'Date', name: 'Date', xtype: 'datefield' }
{ fieldLabel: 'Name', name: 'PerName', xtype: 'textfield' },
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    layout: 'form',
    border: false,
    labelWidth: 200,
    items: [                
        this.fields.check1 = { xtype: 'checkbox', name: 'Check1', fieldLabel: 'Checkbox 1', width: 320 },
        this.fields.check2 = { xtype: 'checkbox', name: 'Check2', fieldLabel: 'Checkbox 2', width: 320 }
    ]
}
```

Here, I am taking the checkboxes inside a panel as I need to increase the label width.
The label is showing but checkbox is not displaying .

What I am doing wrong

Comment: to change the label witdh use `labelWidth` instead of `width`

Comment: @JanS I tried.. it's not working

Comment: could you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

How about you add your checkboxes inside a `FormPanel` something like this:

```
var myPanel = new Ext.form.Panel({
    alias: 'widget.myformPanel',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

    defaults: {
        labelWidth: 100,
    },

    items: [{ 
        xtype: 'checkbox', 
        name: 'Check1', 
        fieldLabel: 'Checkbox 1'
    }, { 
        xtype: 'checkbox', 
        name: 'Check2', 
        fieldLabel: 'Checkbox 2'
    }]
});
```

In that way, you can set the `labelWidth` of the formPanel items.
Try to play it with [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rowena19july/4KeHR/10/).

Answer (score -1):

Build your application with

```
sencha app build
```

It seems that you need to build only for deployment, however, development version uses production css. Therefore, anytime you add a new class you need to build the app to re-create css to include the new class styling.

Comment: Happens to me that `sencha app watch development` shows the box, but `sencha app watch production` does not show it. Do you know what is happening? :( Seems something related to what you say, but `sencha app build [production]` don't fix it.

Comment: First you need to eliminate easy possible reasons for the misbehaving, mainly stale cache - hard-reload the browser several times, clear the browser cache. It can also be a wrong build - re-build with --clean flag, upgrade Sencha cmd, etc. It can also be your own colliding sass/css that overrides Ext defaults. And, lastly, it can be a bug - report it to Sencha.

Comment: It seems `sencha app upgrade` is needed too sometimes :D